# Weird behavior in SELECT UDAF(AGGR()) HAVING

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

There are two select statements:

```
select       max(min(str)) from (select 0 id, 'a' str from dual) group by id having min(str) = 'a';
select strconcat(min(str)) from (select 0 id, 'a' str from dual) group by id having min(str) = 'a';
```

The only difference is the outer-level aggregate function: `max()` vs. `strconcat()`.
You can replace `strconcat()` with any UDAF you have.

The former statement works as expected: it returns string `'a'`.
The latter statement:
 -  (on Oracle 10g) gives wrong result (null instead of string `'a'`)
 -  (on Oracle 11g) raises `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

I don't understand this error message.
Could you please explain this behavior?
Is it an Oracle bug?

Comment: Never came to an idea to use `max(min(...))` but apparently it works (in some cases). Using `min(min(min(...)))` gives me `ORA-00935: group function is nested too deeply` (12.1.0.2.0), which I'd expect in the *double call* case as well.

Answer (score 1):

### 10g:

It seems that `WM_CONCAT` available to me (yes, undocumented, but doesn't matter in this case) or `STRCONCAT` you use (or perhaps some other functions) need to be put a level "up"; see this example:

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production

SQL> select       max(min(str)) result
  2  from (select 0 id, 'a' str from dual)
  3  group by id having min(str) = 'a';

R
-
a

SQL> -- returns NULL, just as you've said
SQL> select wm_concat(min(str)) result
  2  from (select 0 id, 'a' str from dual)
  3  group by id having min(str) = 'a';

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------


SQL> -- but, if we put it a level "up", the result is OK
SQL> select wm_concat(minstr) result
  2  from (select min(str) minstr
  3        from (select 0 id, 'a' str from dual)
  4        group by id having min(str) = 'a'
  5       );

RESULT
---------------------------------------------------------------------
a

SQL>
```

### 11g:

OK, both queries (I'm using `listagg` here):

```
SQL> select       max(min(str)) result
  2  from (select 0 id, 'a' str from dual)
  3  group by id having min(str) = 'a';

R
-
a

SQL>
SQL> select listagg(min(str), ',') within group (order by null) result
  2  from (select 0 id, 'a' str from dual)
  3  group by id having min(str) = 'a';

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
a

SQL>
```

So, is it a bug? I wouldn't know.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't put my UDAF a level "up" because it is inside a correlated subquery (correlated subqueries of depth 2 are not supported in Oracle).